Grounding Strategy for Relays Switching Motor Current
My company uses relays to switch motor current. Next to the traces carrying this motor current, we often have digital and analog signals running in between. We typically use a two-layer PCB for this setup. I’m thinking about the best grounding strategy for such a design.
My colleagues seem to often cut the ground plane beneath the relays. I remember one of them mentioning that this is done to prevent motor current from coupling into the ground plane. I’ve also noticed that they generally don’t place the ground plane anywhere on the board, except for certain areas, e.g., voltage regulators and MCU. These practices seem to go against what I’ve learned: On a two-layer board, I would typically place a continuous ground pour wherever possible and ensure a low-inductance, unimpeded return path to the current source.
I’ve attached two screenshots below. Could you please help me understand what should be done and what shouldn't be done?
Below is a screenshot of how I would pour the ground on the top and bottom layers. Note: Right above the relays, there is a current sensor for each relay. I’ve added a narrow cut to the ground planes between the analog and high-current sections, spanning the entire width, so that both currents meet at the current source.

Below is a different design that follows the grounding strategy my colleague would use.


It would be unusual to have ground planes under the relays. You want isolation, especially if the relays are switching inductive/ noisy loads. I’d also avoid any other tracks in the area. Ground planes are for high frequency signals.

Continuous ground pour is fine until it isn't. Put a bunch of non-ground PTHs next to each other and you've created a slot antenna. DRC can check out even with a high current/high frequency return path that looks like spaghetti when a short trace on another layer or even a jumper is the right move. And of course, the noise coupling you mention.

Your colleague's layout looks far better. You say you want a low inductance, unimpeded return path, but none of your ground pours actually accomplish this. 
This is certainly not a low inductance return path.

This is not a return path at all. And under your relay, it's an antenna.

This has multiple peninsulas to pick up noise.

Same deal here, huge chunk of copper hanging out under a relay for no reason.

This pour necks down, limiting the current capacity.

Etc...
Also, the poor traces under the relays have to go through 8 (!) vias just to get across the section of board that we can see. You talk about unimpeded return paths but are not paying attention to your actual signals. Not that it's an absolute metric of efficient design, but your colleague's layout has 25-odd vias while yours has around 100 for the same section of the circuit, not including stitching vias. Maybe they got pushed off somewhere else, but given the overall cleanness of the design, I tend to doubt it. It also seems to be paying attention to what may be house rules like no 90° corners. To be honest, it looks like you let the auto-router run and poured copper on top of it all. Ground pour has its uses, but you have to know what it's doing for you instead of assuming it will work out.

Thank you for your comments. I agree with everything you mentioned. I’ve redone the layout and was able to remove many of the signal vias, although at the expense of the relay control circuit changing layers.
I'd like to clarify one more thing: If I can ensure that there won't be any copper islands or unconnected copper areas near high-current traces, and that there are enough stitching vias to create a real low-inductance return path, would it be reasonable to have ground pour next to or below high-current traces?

I am skeptical about the utility of ground pours for no reason. I'm not saying it was your process, but I think a lot of ground pours get put in for outdated reasons like designing for home PCB etching or for warping issues that modern board houses have fixed. If you have a real need for a big low inductance return path, then design it in instead of breaking it up into a bunch of odd shapes strung together with vias.
